# Convert TypeScript class to class diagram

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, class, class-diagram

How do you convert following class to class diagram, and how till the relation between `Train` and `Wagon` be?

```
export class Buss{
    id: number;
    maxSpeed: number;
}


export class Train{
    id: number; 
    model: string;
    includesWagons?: Array<Wagon>; //<-- wagons class
}


export class Wagon{
  id: number; 
  length: number;
  weight: number;
}


export class Car{
  id: number;
  passangerSeat: number;

}
```

Also what if there are multiple objects of trains that contain a number of wagons?

Comment: This is neither JSON nor javascript.

Comment: @rayhatfield Right, sorry. I assumed it was as it was similar to JSON. Changed to TypeScript

Comment: It seems that Train has Wagons, so you can draw a `HAS A` arrow between train and wagon. The rest is all unrelated.